# Mobile jQuery and jSon request

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

The idea behind my code is quite simple: The script grabs a first link to image from a json if first link is not an image then it goes to another one until it finds an image. However the code is not working.

```
    $("#main").live('pageinit',function(){

        var url_first = "http://www.reddit.com/r/aww/.json?jsonp=?";
        var url_part1 = "http://www.reddit.com/r/aww/.json?after=";
        var url_part2 = "&jsonp=?";

        $.getJSON(url_first).done(function(json){
            var x = 0;
            var url = json.data.children.data[x].url;
            var length = url.length;
            var checkIfImageUrl = function(){
                if(url[length-1]=== "g"){ //check if Jpg extension
                    $("slodziaki").append('<img src="'+ url +'"/>');
                } else {
                    x+=1;
                    checkIfImageUrl();
                }
            });
            checkIfImageUrl();          
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in a `$( function() { // code } );` block.

Your DOM is not ready for this yet, man!

Comment: It's jquery mobile thus I Can't wrap it in any kind of document.ready block.

Comment: I am not familiar with jquery mobile. Try doing a console.log or alert() to see if the code is actually being called.

Comment: Also, what's the `done` method for? I don't see that in the `getJSON` spec. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a1/experiments/api-viewer/docs/jQuery.getJSON/index.html

Answer (score 0):

put your code in `$("#main").live("pageshow",function(){}` instead of pageinit coz as Straseus said your DOM is not ready yet